# bespeak of my heart / bespeak my heart

Tags: prepositions

I am creating a joke card for my niece and her film director husband.
The content says:

> "Ah, my Darling, my Drama,
>   bespeaketh my deepest heart this day."
>
> "Oh, Truest, I shall, I shall.
>   So, tellest me--what thou thinkest of my shoes?"

(You need to see the pic to get the joke.)

Here, though, I'm curious about the prepositions. It seems to me if he says, "bespeakest of my heart," or he says, "bespeaketh my heart," he is saying two different things and I can choose.

I am also curious about the "of my shoes" preposition. It seems to me that, grammatically-speaking, we can't do without the "of", but its presence changes the tone and rhythm of the line.

Comment: I suppose you could write the final part *what thou of my shoes thinkest*. That prevents it from ending on the single syllable. (It's a poem, so even if it's not entirely correct, it doesn't matter.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about archaic usages that learners would do well to avoid completely.

Comment: ...note that if you *really* want to sound "mock Elizabethan", and you don't like the preposition ***of** my shoes* - it would probably be more "authentic" if you said *What thinkst thou **to** my shoes?* Your version just looks like a "word-by-word" literal translation from modern English *What do you think of my shoes?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Nope; *think of* is perfectly good EModE. "What think'st thou of the fair Sir Eglamour?" --*2Gent*

Comment: @StoneyB: Yeah, I know ***of*** is perfectly okay for the context, but apparently OP doesn't like it for some reason. And whereas ***to*** wouldn't be idiomatic today, I think I'm on fairly safe ground saying it *would* have been perfectly acceptable a few centuries ago. And even though an *actual* Elizabethan would probably have been more likely to use ***of*** anyway (not sure, but I'd guess that to be the case), from the perspective of the modern ear it seems to me it sounds more "authentically antiquated" if you include usages that *aren't* idiomatically valid today.

Comment: @Lambie In EModE *bespeak* often has the sense "speak to [OBJ]", as in *Ham* "my young mistress thus I did bespeak", meaning Polonius spoke *to* Ophelia in such-and-such terms.

Comment: @StoneyB So, parse the sentence for me and above all parse the I shall.

Comment: I think it depends on whether you want to go for accurate Elizabethan or something like it that is deliberately wrong for humorous effect.  For example, there's a quote from "The Avengers" (2012), *Doth mother know you weareth her drapes?*  I won't go into the full context, the point being it *sounds* like Shakespeare but is slightly ungrammatical -- which is fine, because it's not meant to be anything other than an example of  [Ye Olde Butcherede Englishe](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YeOldeButcheredeEnglishe)

Comment: @Lambie I *will* (as you request) speak to your heart: what (O heart) do you think of my shoes? The joke, of course, is the bathos of the utterance.

Comment: @Lambie  O my darling, my drama\*, speak to my deepest heart today. ... *I have no idea what "drama" is intended to mean in this context; I imagine it's some sort of family joke about the husband's profession

Answer (score 1):

In EModE, as in ModE, imperatives employed the plain form, and might include the subject in the next position. Questions might invert ordinary verbs and not just auxiliaries.

> Ah, my Darling, my Drama, **bespeak** (thou) my deepest heart this day.
>   Oh, Truest, I shall, I shall. So, **tell** (thou) me--what **think'st thou** of my shoes?

Comment: We are not convinced. What dost thou stir up, pray tell?

Comment: You didn't parse the first bit. I understand the "what do you think of my shoes" part. I still think it's gibberish.  One speaker says: tell me Heart, etc. The other says: Oh Truest, I shall [speak to you]. What do you think of my shoes? But, the bespeaking does not work.

Comment: Just curious for your opinion, StoneyB – do you think this ought to be migrated to [elu.se]?

Comment: @J.R. It's not the sort of question that's likely to do our ordinary clientele much good. But are ELLs invariably E2Ls? :)